# Invalid Sesion Id Selenium WebDriver C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have this error:

```
Mensaje: 
    Excepción método de prueba Gmg.Rapiweb.Selenium.Test.Processes.RW_CR.Process_Cotizacion_Contado.Process_Cotizacion_Contado_Test: 
    OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: invalid session id
```

It tells me that it is on line 82 of the next code

This happens two or three attempts ago, because it did not happen before

This is my code. In this case I login and then I make a quotation:

```
using System; using System.Text;  using System.Text.RegularExpressions; using System.Threading;  using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;  using OpenQA.Selenium; using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;  using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI; using Gmg.Rapiweb.Selenium.Test.Variables;  using System.Drawing.Imaging; using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;  using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Gmg.Rapiweb.Selenium.Test.Processes.RW_CR {
    [TestClass]
    public class Process_Cotizacion_Contado
    {
        private StringBuilder verificationErrors;
        private static string baseURL;
        private bool acceptNextAlert = true;
        Helpers helpers = new Helpers();
        private string cedula = "11-1111-1111";

        [ClassInitialize]
        public static void InitializeClass(TestContext testContext)
        {
            Variables_RW.driver = new ChromeDriver();
            baseURL = "https://www.google.com/";
        }

        [ClassCleanup]
        public static void CleanupClass()
        {
            try
            {
                //driver.Quit();// quit does not close the window
                Variables_RW.driver.Close();
                Variables_RW.driver.Dispose();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                // Ignore errors if unable to close the browser
            }
        }

        [TestInitialize]
        public void InitializeTest()
        {
            verificationErrors = new StringBuilder();
        }

        [TestCleanup]
        public void CleanupTest()
        {
            Assert.AreEqual("", verificationErrors.ToString());
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void Process_Cotizacion_Contado_Test()
        {

            Process_Login login = new Process_Login();
            login.Process_Login_Test();

            try
            {
                Variables_RW.driver.FindElement(By.XPath("(//A[@class='btn btn-lg btnInicio'])[2]")).Click();
                helpers.VisualizaObjeto(By.XPath("//P[text()='Cargando cotizador... Espere por favor...']"), 10, Variables_RW.driver);
                helpers.EsperaCargar(3);
                helpers.EsperaObjeto(By.XPath("//BUTTON[@id='btnMenuHeader2LineaNuevaCotizacion']"), 5, Variables_RW.driver);

                helpers.EsperaCargar(5);

                Screenshot CotizacionContado = ((ITakesScreenshot)Variables_RW.driver).GetScreenshot();
                CotizacionContado.SaveAsFile("D://Users/wa5699cr/Documents/Proyectos 2020/Automatización de procesos/RW Pre-producción/Evidencias/Cotización/Contado/cotización1.png",
                    ScreenshotImageFormat.Png);
                Buscar_Persona();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Screenshot CotizacionContado1 = ((ITakesScreenshot)Variables_RW.driver).GetScreenshot();
                CotizacionContado1.SaveAsFile("D://Users/wa5699cr/Documents/Proyectos 2020/Automatización de procesos/RW Pre-producción/Evidencias/Cotización/Contado/cotizaciónError1.png",
                    ScreenshotImageFormat.Png);
                Variables_RW.driver.Close();
                throw ex;
            }
        }
```

This is login code:

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Threading;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;
using Gmg.Rapiweb.Selenium.Test.Variables;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;

namespace Gmg.Rapiweb.Selenium.Test.Processes.RW_CR
{
    [TestClass]
    public class Process_Login
    {
        private StringBuilder verificationErrors;
        private static string baseURL;
        private bool acceptNextAlert = true;
        Helpers helpers = new Helpers();

        [ClassInitialize]
        public static void InitializeClass(TestContext testContext)
        {
            Variables_RW.driver = new ChromeDriver();
            baseURL = "https://www.google.com/";
        }

        [ClassCleanup]
        public static void CleanupClass()
        {
            try
            {
                //driver.Quit();// quit does not close the window
                Variables_RW.driver.Close();
                Variables_RW.driver.Dispose();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                // Ignore errors if unable to close the browser
            }
        }

        [TestInitialize]
        public void InitializeTest()
        {
            verificationErrors = new StringBuilder();
        }

        [TestCleanup]
        public void CleanupTest()
        {
            Assert.AreEqual("", verificationErrors.ToString());
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void Process_Login_Test()
        {
            //Maximiza el navegador
            Variables_RW.driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();

            //Entra a la url
            Variables_RW.driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(Variables_RW.url);

            //LLena espacios del incio de sesión
            SelectElement spais = new SelectElement(Variables_RW.driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//SELECT[@id='pais']")));
            spais.SelectByText("Costa Rica");
            Variables_RW.driver.FindElement(By.Id("user")).Click();
            Variables_RW.driver.FindElement(By.Id("user")).Clear();
            Variables_RW.driver.FindElement(By.Id("user")).SendKeys(Variables_RW.usuario);
            Variables_RW.driver.FindElement(By.Id("password")).Click();
            Variables_RW.driver.FindElement(By.Id("password")).Clear();
            Variables_RW.driver.FindElement(By.Id("password")).SendKeys(Variables_RW.password);

            Screenshot loginImage = ((ITakesScreenshot)Variables_RW.driver).GetScreenshot();
            loginImage.SaveAsFile("D://Users/wa5699cr/Documents/Proyectos 2020/Automatización de procesos/RW Pre-producción/Evidencias/Login/login.png",
                ScreenshotImageFormat.Png);


            Variables_RW.driver.FindElement(By.Id("btnSignIn")).Click();
            helpers.EsperaObjeto(By.XPath("//BUTTON[@id='btnSelect']"), 30, Variables_RW.driver);
            Thread.Sleep(5 * 1000);
            //driver.Manage().Timeouts().PageLoad = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);

            //Seleccionar tienda y entrar
            SelectElement stienda = new SelectElement(Variables_RW.driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//select[@id='tiendas']")));
            stienda.SelectByText(Variables_RW.tienda_1);
            Thread.Sleep(2 * 1000);

            Screenshot loginImage1 = ((ITakesScreenshot)Variables_RW.driver).GetScreenshot();
            loginImage1.SaveAsFile("D://Users/wa5699cr/Documents/Proyectos 2020/Automatización de procesos/RW Pre-producción/Evidencias/Login/login1.png",
                ScreenshotImageFormat.Png);

            Variables_RW.driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//BUTTON[@id='btnSelect']")).Click();

            helpers.EsperaObjeto(By.XPath("(//A[@class='btn btn-lg btnInicio'])[2]"), 12, Variables_RW.driver);
            Thread.Sleep(2 * 1000);
            Variables_RW.driver.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

I have a class "Variables" when I have all of variables burned for loging and other processes

Comment: using driver.Close() will close the browser if it's the last window/tab open.  Then you have no session.

Comment: Then I should use driver.Quit(); ?

Comment: you should, yes... but make sure you don't use those commands before the tests are complete.  The error you are seeing sort of indicates that the browser has closed, but the driver is still running tasks.  It can also indicate that multiple driver processes are running but one has grabbed a sessionID from a closing process.

Comment: in this proyect each test class is a process of the app. I should close the process in the end of each test class. In the last function I'm using "Variables_RW.driver.Close();"

I believe that I should for "Variables_RW.driver.Quit();"

Comment: that sounds right.. so what could be happening is when the next driver instance is launched, it grabs a sessionID from a browser that is still in the process of closing.   If you see this error happen again, add a sleep in between quitting a driver and initiating a new one.

Comment: All right. Thank u for your help